# Jquery load div auto scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

Como fazer alto scoll ao carregar a página?

Estou tentando fazer assim, mas sem sucesso!

Arquivo: mensagens.php

```
$('.chatUsuariosLista').click(function() {
            idUsuario = this.id;
            $("#chatMsg").load('inc_chatMensagens.php?de='+idUsuario+'&para='+$("#para").val());
            $("#para").val(idUsuario);

            $('#chat2').attr({scrollTop: $('#chat2').attr('scrollHeight')});

        });
```

Tentei colocar o codigo `$('#chat2').attr({scrollTop: $('#chat2').attr('scrollHeight')});` dentro do arquivo inc_chatMensagens.php, mas tambem não funciona.

Arquivo inc_chatMensagens.php

```
<div id="chat2">
    <ul>
        <?php while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {?>

            <?php if ($_GET['de'] == $row['de']) {?>
                <li>
                    <div class="bubble">
                        <span class="personName">Cliente:</span> <br>
                        <span class="personSay"><?php echo $row['msg']; ?></span> <br>
                        <span class="time"><?php echo $row['data']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="bubble2">
                        <span class="personName2">Você:</span> <br>
                        <span class="personSay2"><?php echo $row['msg']; ?></span><br>
                        <span class="time2"><?php echo $row['data']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Talvez esteja procurando pela função [`.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Sintaxe)?

Comment: @MateusA. Vi que não funciona na maioria dos navegadores.

Comment: Não enviei como resposta necessariamente por isso. Sua questão está um pouco confusa, você quer fazer o scroll subir até o topo, ou até alguma outra mensagem? Se for direto para o topo, [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147118/7225971) resposta pode te ajudar (Além da animação). Porém se for para um elemento definido, selecione-o e execute a função, exemplo: `document.getElementById("bubble").scrollIntoView();`, poderia testar para ver se está tudo em ordem?

Comment: @MateusA. Estou tentando deixar o scroll sempre em baixo como em bate papo onde as mensagens vão aparecendo e o scroll descendo automaticamente.

Comment: Sei que você está usando elementos do tipo `li` para identificar as mensagens pelo codigo que você apagou, então tente usar isso: `$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $('ul#mensagens li:last').offset().top});` (baseado [nesse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8334845/7225971) post) Nesse caso usei `ul#mensagens`, então você deve adicionar um `id="mensagens"` para seu elemento do tipo `ul`.

Comment: Aqui está um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/GEsmb/155/

Comment: @MateusA. Bom dia. Funcionou em parte...rsrs. Esta funcionando na tela toda e não somente no scoll da div.

Comment: A sim, perdão... entendi a pergunta de outra forma. Vou publicar como resposta agora...

Answer (score 1):

A função que você procura é [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742972/7225971):

```
function descer(){
  var elm    = $('.chat');
  var height = elm[0].scrollHeight;
  elm.scrollTop(height);
}
```

Ela será responsável por obter o seu elemento de classe `chat`, e logo após irá até o fim do elemento (posição obtida através da altura).
Aqui está um teste para conferir o resultado:

Fiddle original do autor: http://jsfiddle.net/y430ovjt/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wtf = $('.chat');
  var height = wtf[0].scrollHeight;
  wtf.scrollTop(height);
});

// Nota: Script foi colocado acima (<script>)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function descer() {
    var elm = $('.chat');
    var height = elm[0].scrollHeight;
    elm.scrollTop(height);
  }

  function add() {
    $("ul#mensagens").append("<li>Novo Item</li>");
    descer();
  }
</script>
<h3>Item Teste</h3>
<div class="chat" style="background-color: lightgray; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <ul id="mensagens">
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
    <li>Exemplo</li>
  </ul> <button onclick="add()">Adicionar</button>
</div>
<h3>Item Teste</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui usando apenas CSS. Pesquisando achei esse comentário https://stackoverflow.com/a/44051405/3939389

Solução para quem tiver o mesmo problema
`display: flex;` e `flex-direction: column-reverse;`

```
<div class="row" id="chatMsg" style="padding: 7px; overflow-y: scroll;display: flex;flex-direction: column-reverse;"></div>
```

Agradeço a todos que se colocaram a disposição.